# Yammer REST API: How to get list of groups for external network?

Tags: authorization, permalinks, yammer

I've an application that need to get list of groups for external network of Yammer. Until last time it's worked so:

1. /api/v1/oauth/tokens.json brought list of tokens\networks AND COOKIES: **yamtrak_id**=[id from yammer], **_workfeed_session_id**=[session id from yammer] during "Authorization Bearer [access_token]"
2. The permalink https://www.yammer.com/name_of_my_network/api/v1/groups.json with this cookies brought list of groups

Now, when I've signed up with Yammer and took **new access token**, then /api/v1/oauth/tokens.json **respond without this cookies**

But when I've used **old access token**, that was created since two months, /api/v1/oauth/tokens.json ** brings an answer with this cookies**

How to get list of groups without permalink or how to make "right" session that works with permalink?